# How can BERT/Transformer models accept input batches of different sizes?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, transformers, llm

I understand that all inputs in a batch need to be of the same size. However, it seems BERT/Transformers models can accept batches with different sizes as input.

How is that possible? I thought we needed to pad all examples in a batch to `model.max_input_size`, however, it seems HuggingFace does `Dynamic Padding` that allows sending batches of different lengths (till the time they are smaller than `max_input_size`)

[image]

Link: https://mccormickml.com/2020/07/29/smart-batching-tutorial/
Link2: https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/en/chapter3/2?fw=pt#dynamic-padding